# Export dynamic query results to different spreadsheets in an excel file

Tags: sql-server-2012, export-to-excel

I have a validation tool that needs to be run ~300 times for various inputs.  I'm planning to use a cursor to loop through all the required inputs (as the validation query is created dynamically)

I've been asked to export all this information to an excel file (separated into unique sheets for each of the ~300 resulsets.).

From what I've read about SSIS, it isn't able to export dynamically created queries into an excel file (if I'm mistaken, please correct me!).

I've also tried using dbo.sp_OACreate, but the security settings on the server I'm using disallow me from doing so.

Is there another way to export my ~300 resultsets into an excel spreadsheet programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that there is no way to do this using sql server 2012.  I ended up using a CLR program to query and export the data to an excel spreadsheet.

I used datasets to run my queries and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library to export it to a spreadsheet.